# Configure 'Save on losing focus' in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text-editor

Is it possible either in the standard build or via a extension to make visual studio 2010 save all unsaved work when I switch focus to another application.

It's a feature that IntelliJ and TextMate do rather well (spot the Java developer learning C#) and it means I've gotten out of the habit of saving changes before I switch to the browser and hit refresh.

Note I'm not expecting *real* code to just work like this, I'm kinda hoping that changes to views and scripts can be saved on `alt+tab`

Answer (score 3):

Someone made an add-in which does the job, go to http://cbates.net/document-autosave-for-visual-studio/

UPDATE:
Beware in VS2015 it seems that sln/csproj files are not being saved when focus is lost. This can cause some pain when you pull latest changes outside VS and forget to save project manually.

Comment: oh that does look good.. if somebody else can confirm this does actually work (I don't have a copy of VS anymore) then I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, been using it for a few months now without issues.

Comment: I've just started using it with VS2013 and it does seem to work.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2013 the extension name is CBExtensionPkg, use that to search in the gallery

Answer (score 0):

You can configure an auto-save option that allows you to set a number of minutes and VS saves everytime that number of minutes is hit, its not exactly what you require but is an option you can consider.

To configure this option, go to Tools \ Options and then click on AutoRecover in the Environment section:

[image]

Comment: it would work but only if it could handle an interval of a second or so

Comment: ah.. my colleague informs me that the saved files actually go into a special auto recover area, hence it wouldn't be visible to the Dev web server.